# What's a recommended alternative to Quickbooks pro?

Tags: software-recommendation

I've just installed Ubuntu to replace Windows. I can't seem to find a good alternative to [Quickbooks pro](http://quickbooks.intuit.com/pro/) to run on Ubuntu. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't their a web version of Quickbooks?

Comment: I have been searching for a long time for a replacement for Quicken or Quickbooks. I have not found anything with the same power on Linx.

Comment: Not many people around here will be familiar with Quickbooks. It would help if you could list the key features of the application and which of them are of great value to you. Also, include any other requirements, e.g. migration support from Quickbooks to the alternative.

Comment: quicken is a money management software afaik, if we're talking about the same software, run a search for microsoft money alternatives in the web, you are going to find excellent recommendations. Sorry if I am wrong and I am in a cellphone right now. Please inform if you suceed in order to include an answer later in a pc. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

There are a variety of alternatives to QuickBooks, if you're looking for a web-based option. Or, as Jackson Doak mentioned, there is [GnuCash](http://gnucash.org/) - open source & desktop. It's a pretty robust accounting software and certainly worth exploring, if you prefer a desktop alternative to QuickBooks.

If you're open to web-based options, then have a look at [Wave](https://www.waveapps.com/) (completely free), [Monchilla](http://www.monchilla.com/) or [Outright](http://outright.com/) (both free/paid options). QuickBooks does have an [online version](http://quickbooks.intuit.com/online-1/) available and there's [Xero](https://www.xero.com/) also.

It will depend on your accounting needs, as much as your chosen platform. I'm a certified advisor and user of QuickBooks, as well as the web-based software options I listed.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could install quickbook via wine, if that's too much hassle, you could try:

- Gnucash,
- kmymoney and
- moneydance

They may be what you're after, they all have got decent reviews.

Comment: While I use Ubuntu as my main driver, I still use Windows software for some specialized needs either using Crossover, Play-on-Linux, or using virtual machines that I have set up that run XP or Windows 7 (I use VirtualBox). IMHO QuickBooks is a very evolved product and you are likely to NOT find a suitable alternative in Linux.

Comment: Hi Jackson Doak and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a good answer, but it could be improved. It's very brief, and not *exceptionally* great - which is what we hope the Ask Ubuntu community strives for. I would suggest **including the reviews - or links to them.** This would make it much easier to research the programs you have suggested, and make the answer worthy of upvotes (which give you 10 reputation each time) and appreciation from the Internet. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

For medium to Large size businesses I'd highly recommend Quasar Accounting http://linuxcanada.com/. The Business I work for is running it. We have 6 branches and they are all connected. I also give support for 3 smaller businesses (Less then 5 employees) that use Quasar. The Single user addition is free and the older versions you can even get GPL licensed source code for. To download visit ftp://linuxcanada.com/pub/Quasar/

Comment: Could you instead explain the advantage and/or characteristics of Quasar?